# How to set a date of an html5 datepicker using appium in android?

Tags: android, python, robotframework, appium

I'm trying to create automated tests for a hybrid app which has an html5 date input type. 
I'm using Appium in combination with robot framework (python) and I try to use the Appium library for the robot framework as much as possible.

For some reason I can't set the date of the datepicker. I've tried a couple of different things:

- Using input text (send keys) on the datepicker input
- Clicking on the datepicker so it opens up the popup date selector
  And then trying to set the individual fields using different locators such as:

**Name** (The name changes once you send a key to the field which causes the next 
i've tried:

```
name=Sep
```

But when i try to put in Jan it stops after the J has been entered.

**Xpath** (for some reason this returns all fields where it should only return 1 field)
i've tried the following xpath locators:

```
//android.widget.DatePicker//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText
//android.widget.DatePicker//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Increase month"/../android.widget.EditText
```

this is the structure of the datepicker

```
  Datepicker
      LinearLayout
        LinearLayout
          LinearLayout
            ImageButton {increase month}
            EditText:Sep
            ImageButton {decrease month}
          LinearLayout
            ImageButton {increase day}
            EditText:29
            ImageButton {decrease day}
          LinearLayout
            ImageButton {increase year}
            EditText:2014
            ImageButton {decrease year}
```

I can't think of anything else to do to set the date of the datepicker.
Is there an easy way to set the date for the html5 datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

Try using xpath like this:

```
//android.widget.DatePicker[@index='0']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='1']/android.widget.EditText[@text='example']
```

If you add proper indexes or other properties, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I use java, the code maybe different.

instead of "send key", I use javascript for input. working in my test.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]",
                                       driver.findElement(By.id("date")),
                                       Date);
```

remember, the Data format must fit for the rules, otherwise it will do nothing. 
to know the format your page use is easy. just pick one date manually and check the value in page source (notice the data format present on page may not the right one).

Hope this helps.